# How to sign jar on Mac OS X using installed .p12 certificate?

Tags: java, macos, jar, codesign, jarsigner

I am trying to sign myApp.jar on Mac OS X.I have installed p12 certificate on my Mac Os X machine. and to Sign app I use this following command -

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
```

codesign -s "my name" MyApp.app

For signing app I do not provide the path of installed p12 certificate explicitly.

Similar I want to sign MyApp.jar on Mac Os X. I know the command to sign jar on Windows that is -

> jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore path_of_local_folder/myFile.p12 -storepass myPass
>   myApp.jar "my alias"

Actually my purpose to create app and dmg for myApp using that signed jar. So I need to sign that jar first before creating app and dmg. For that I already have installed "myFile.p12" on my Mac OS X machine. I need that argument of jarsigner **-keystore** should take .p12 certificate that already installed my machine. I do not wish to keep one copy of .p12 in local folder and give its path to -keystore argument.

Please let me know how can I sign jar on Mac with using installed .p12 certificate??

Thank you for your help in advance

Neelam Sharma

Comment: Are you talking about a key pair that is held in a [Mac OS X "keychain"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) rather than a PKCS #12 file on the files system?

Comment: @erickson I have updated my question for clarification.